# Workflow Email alert displays my name instead of the user's name for whom the conditions are met

Tags: workflow, user, email-alert, username

I've got a custom field on user object. The requirement is whenever conditions are met for this custom field, an email needs to be triggered along with the name of the user.

I've created a workflow rule for this and I am able to receive emails whenever the conditions are met. The template I've created looks like 'Conditions are met for {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}'.

This template worked perfectly fine, when I chose the action type as chatter. However in case of email alert, it always displays my name instead of the user's name for whom the conditions are met. Example:'Conditions are met for MY NAME'. Please can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, using the merge syntax `{!User.FirstName}` in an email template will merge fields from the current user into the email template.

You should read this article here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_user_object_limitations.htm&type=5

Which explains in detail how to merge in fields from the User object for the "target" record. In summary, the syntax is `{!Target_User.FirstName}`.
This is in beta however, and a few months back when I was doing this via HTML and text email templates, the values weren't merging correctly.

The solution for me was to use a VisualForce Email Template, and use the `{!RelatedTo.FirstName}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {!User.FirstName}, why not use {![object].LastModifiedBy}? I mean the last person who satisfied that field should be the last person who edited it when the WF triggers.